# Найти строку в запросе SELECT, вызывающую ошибку

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Никак не могу придумать как найти строку в выборке, которая вызывает ошибку в запросе. Желательно иметь `rowid` этой строки. Единственная идея - это считывать `rowid` в начале, а потом выбирать эту строку уже с условиями по `rowid`. Но так надо пройтись по всему множеству строк, не ограниченных никаким условием.

Может будут какие-то идеи? Насколько понимаю, `exception` в этом случае ничем не поможет, если свалиться в него на этой строке все равно не получиться узнать ее `rowid`.

Единственное что придумал:

```
declare

    v varchar2(1000);

begin
    for c in 
    (
        select rowid from tbl where int_period = 201809
    )
    loop
        v := c.rowid;

        begin

        for t in
        (
            select * from tbl where rowid = c.rowid and regexp_replace(field,'[^-[0-9]]') < 0 -- Допустим ошибка в этом условии
        )
        loop
            null;
        end loop;

        exception
        when others then

            dbms_output.put_line(v||' - '||sqlerrm);

        end;

    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: О какой ошибке идёт речь?

Comment: Вообще о любой. В данном случае это может быть преобразование к числу. Например: select 1  from dual where regexp_replace('-15A002350699','[^[0-9]]') > 0 То есть некоторые строки проверку условия пройдут нормально, а на некоторых будет возникать ошибка из - за условия

Comment: Боюсь, что универсального способа нет. Нужно разбираться в каких случаях возникают ошибки и отсеивать их, например, усиливая регулярное выражение. «Придуманный» вариант должен помочь отловить ошибки, если с этим возникают проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо. Тогда буду его использовать. Думал может кто уже придумал что-то более универсальное.

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст Пожалуйста. Для данной конкретной проверки можете использовать регулярку проверки числа с `REGEXP_LIKE`, либо написать функцию [`IS_NUMERIC`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819709/how-can-you-tell-if-a-value-is-not-numeric-in-oracle). Так можно будет найти ошибочные строки одним запросом.

Comment: Спасибо, но меня в более общем плане этот вопрос интересовал. Но на заметку возьму ))

Answer (score 3):

Логирование ошибок на уровне строк реализовано для DML выражений: `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE`  с предикатом [LOG ERRORS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9015.htm#SQLRF55061). Почему не для `SELECT`? Основная идея - не допустить полного отката транзакции, если ошибка только в нескольких строчках.

Для обычного запроса достаточно проверить, в каких строчках возможно возникнет ошибка.
Пример данных с 3-мя ошибочными строками:

```
create table tbl as 
    select 
        rownum id, 
        lpad (case when mod (rownum, 30) != 0 then ''||rownum else chr (rownum+32) end, 10, '0') code
    from xmlTable ('1 to 100')
;
```

И цикл в вопросе будет выглядеть так:

```
select * from (
    select rowid, t.*, validate_conversion (code as number) convertible
    from tbl t
) where convertible = 0 
;

ROWID                      ID CODE                                     CONVERTIBLE
------------------ ---------- ---------------------------------------- -----------
AAAgecAAMAAAgDTAAd         30 000000000>                                         0
AAAgecAAMAAAgDTAA7         60 000000000\                                         0
AAAgecAAMAAAgDTABZ         90 000000000z                                         0
```